# Unable to install tailwind css in react using npm

Tags: css, reactjs

I recently started learning React js. I familiar with tailwind css ands tart instlaling it using documentation. At the third step when i have to install craco i start facing error. I too intsall the older version which work. but after that at last npm start i start facing error again. what to do. anybody help me out.

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

npm run start

[image]

using npm run start

[image]

Comment: try ```npm i react-scripts@latest```

Comment: Test this too  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11777

Comment: tried npm i react-scripts@latest but still facing error.